# How to convert this SQL query to LINQ to Entities query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, linq-to-entities

I need help to convert a SQL query to entity query in my C# code.
The query combines 4 different tables together which is as follows:

```
SELECT a.email,
       a.status,
       a.createdat,
       b.unitprice,
       c.name,
       d.name,
       e.name 
FROM Orders a, 
     Orderdetails b, 
     ServiceOptions c, 
     services d, 
     merchants e 
WHERE a.id=b.orderid AND c.id=b.serviceoptionid
      AND c.serviceid=d.id AND d.merchantid=e.id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = from a in context.Orders
            join b in context.OrderDetails on a.id equals b.orderid
            join c in context.ServiceOptions on b.serviceoptionid equals c.id
            join d in context.services on c.serviceid equals d.id
            join e in context.merchants on d.merchantid equals e.id
            select new { a.email, 
                         a.status, 
                         a.createdat,
                         b.unitprice, 
                         c.name, 
                         d.name, 
                         e.name };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going the opposite direction. Create a entity framework first and then use LINQ from the EF to create the SQL. It should be EF->LINQ-SQL. The whole idea of EF is the user doesn't have to create a sql. This query can be done in LINQ to SQL after EF is created in the project.